# Read two files which has json data and create new dictionary using 2 files data

Tags: python, json, dictionary, input, file-io

My files have data as

file1.txt

```
Student={'name'='john','age'=13,'roll_no':22445,'gender'='male'},{'name'='jimmy','age'=14,'roll_no':45622,'gender'='male'}
```

file2.txt

```
Address1={'name':'john','roll_no'=22445,'street':'st johns','pin':56902,'country':'US'},{'name':'jimmy','roll_no'=45622,'street':'st peters','pin':56502,'country':'US'}
```

when i read the file and try loading it to json.i was getting list instead of dict

```
with open('file1.txt','r') as inputfile1:
        new_file=json.dumps(inputfile1)
        new_file=json.loads(new_file)

with open('file2.txt','r') as inputfile2:
        new_file2=json.dumps(inputfile2)
        new_file2=json.loads(new_file2)

print(type(new_file1))
print(type(new_file2))
```

New to python, can someone help

Comment: Those files are not valid JSON. You need to fix that first.

Comment: Other than that your code is just ... confused? What do you want to achieve with `new_file=json.dumps(inputfile1)`? Have you read any documentation?

Comment: the json data is stored to a variable and saved in a file, how can i fix this?

Comment: provide a [mcve] with your variables and your actual data.

Answer (score -1):

Ur data into files is invalid json string. Try make better it valid json before write data into files. If it impossible, here is example how to fix it:

```
import json
Student='''{'name'='john','age'=13,'roll_no':22445,'gender'='male'},{'name'='jimmy','age'=14,'roll_no':45622,'gender'='male'}'''
Address1='''{'name':'john','roll_no'=22445,'street':'st johns','pin':56902,'country':'US'},{'name':'jimmy','roll_no'=45622,'street':'st peters','pin':56502,'country':'US'}'''

#make valid json of ur string
Address1=Address1.replace("'",'"') #replace single quotes to double
Address1=Address1.replace('=',':') #
Address1='['+Address1+']'

a=json.loads(Address1)


Student=Student.replace("'",'"') #replace single quotes to double
Student=Student.replace('=',':') #
Student='['+Student+']'

s=json.loads(Student)

#type(a)
#<class 'list'>

a.extend(s)
print(a)
'''
[{'name': 'john', 'roll_no': 22445, 'street': 'st johns', 'pin': 56902, 'country
': 'US'}, {'name': 'jimmy', 'roll_no': 45622, 'street': 'st peters', 'pin': 5650
2, 'country': 'US'}, {'name': 'john', 'age': 13, 'roll_no': 22445, 'gender': 'ma
le'}, {'name': 'jimmy', 'age': 14, 'roll_no': 45622, 'gender': 'male'}]
'''
```